# How do i access the value of a custom type that i have stored in a Claim from Webapi controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have added some claim information, "id" to the JWT token in my custom token generate

```
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("id", user.Id.ToString()), new Claim( ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role ) }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
```

When i tried to access the Claim type "id" from the Claim it gives me a run time error

Code to access Claim

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            //var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            //if (identity != null)
            //{
            //    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
            //    // or


            //}


            var id = User.FindFirst("id").Value;

        //some code here to access servce 
}
```

Error i'm getting at line  `var id = User.FindFirst("id").Value;`

[image]

**UPDATE**
Here is the screenshot that shows the user is valid and its "id" was added to Claim

[image]

**update**

Here is my custom Authorize attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {

        public AuthorizeAttribute()
        {
            
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var user = (User)context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                // not logged in
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
            }
        }
    }
```

Why it throws the error and how do i access "id" in the claim?

Comment: Probably need to start by inspecting the claims that _are_ defined in your User. A few questions: when is your `SecurityTokenDescriptor` called, and was your current authenticated user created before adding this code?

Comment: @ Tieson T yes, it created in the tokenGenerator and the id is extracted from the authenticated user

Comment: Not entirely sure that we're understanding each other, but if this security token was created on the same request in which you're trying to read it, you will likely run into errors, as the token probably hasn't been propagated to the request context.

Comment: @TiesonT. i have updates my original post with screen shot that shows claims has "id" with value

Comment: @TiesonT. are you saying the user is not in HttpsContext?

Comment: Depending on how this code is being accessed, it's entirely possible for HttpContext to be null or `User` (which is mapped to the UserPrincipal on the current HttpContext) to be null. `User` won't be populated if you're trying to read it in the same request as it was created, normally. You're not really showing enough to make more than (what amount to) guesses, though.

Comment: @TiesonT. i have checked, The user does not exist in HttpContext.User.Claims

Comment: try by applying `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller

Comment: @WaqasRaja i use custom Authorize attribute, wonder how it should be handled in it, i have updated the original post with my custom authorize attribute

Answer (score -1):

i was able to solve the issue by attaching the current authenticated user to the `HttpContext`